# Can't install airvpn dependencies in Debian Sid

Tags: debian, sid

I downloaded Airvpn to my Debian sid OS.  I've installed several dependencies already listed, but I keep getting the following print-out:

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of airvpn:  airvpn
>   depends on libmono-system-runtime2.0-cil; however:   Package
>   libmono-system-runtime2.0-cil is not installed.  airvpn depends on
>   libmono-winforms2.0-cil; however:   Package libmono-winforms2.0-cil is
>   not installed.  airvpn depends on libmono-corlib2.0-cil; however:
>   Package libmono-corlib2.0-cil is not installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing package airvpn (--install):  dependency
>   problems - leaving unconfigured Processing triggers for man-db
>   (2.7.6.1-2) ... Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-8) ...
>   Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ... Processing
>   triggers for mime-support (3.60) ... Errors were encountered while
>   processing:  airvpn

The packages still listed are 'uninstallable' according to the terminal.  Is there a solution to this, or should I just try for a refund?

Answer (score 0):

it seams that at least `libmono-system-runtime2.0-cil` isn't in the sid-repo (didn't bother to check the rest, since you could simply google that yourself) see here https://packages.debian.org/jessie/cli-mono/libmono-system-runtime2.0-cil

So either add jessie to your source.list and get the package from there or (**what i would highly recommend to you**) re-install as jessie, add sid to your source.list and only download those package you actually need from sid. there should be absolutely no need to run a whole sid installation.

also, you could have just googled that yourself, which took about 30 seconds.